# mysqli not displaying image from database

Tags: php, database, image, mysqli

Im changing everything to mysqli and because im just learning its pretty hard. What am i doing wrong? my images appear broken and prints the file name, I know this is a simple question but ive tried searching the internet with no result. sorry im learning

```
<?php 
include_once("db_conex.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY price ASC";
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$query);

if($result = mysqli_query($db,$query)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
        echo "<br /><br />";
        echo '<img src="/upload/ " border=0>', $row->photo;
        echo "<br /><br />";
        echo '<b> City: </b>', $row->city;
        echo '<b> Price: </b>', $row->price;
        echo '<b> Bath: </b>', $row->bath;           
        echo '<b> Bath: </b>', $row->bed;
        echo '<b> Description: </b>', $row->description;
        echo '<b> Link: </b>', $row->link; 
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
//Close Connection
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: @ First question here, please read what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
echo '<img src="/upload/ " border=0>', $row->photo;
```

You are literally just printing an empty (probably non-existant) image, followed by the filename. You probably meant:

```
echo '<img src="/upload/' . $row->photo . '" border=0>';
```